# Zeros of Airy function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there any function that returns the  Zeros of the Airy function in Matlab?

I am using Matlab 7.11.0.

Thanks!

Comment: How many zeros do you want returned?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor - ALL infinitely many of them, of course. Silly question. It may take some time though. And some memory.

Comment: Man, that's a silly response.. There is always the pure mathematical expression, and than there is evaluation of the expression in the computer. The answer serves the purpose of the original question though, so I'll modify it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function a = airyZeros(N)
#AIRYZEROS Computes the first N zeros of the Airy function
#
#    Example
#       >> airyZeros(3)
#       ans =
#          -2.3381   -4.0880   -5.5206

    a = NaN(1,N);

    for n = 1:N
        switch n
            case 1
                x = -2.3381;
            case 2
                x = -4.08795;
            case 3
                x = -5.52056;
            case 4
                x = -6.7867144;
            case 5
                x = -7.94413;
            case 6
                x = -9.02265;
            otherwise
                x = -(3*pi/2 * (n-0.25))^(2/3);
        end

        a(n) = real(fsolve(@airy, x, optimset('display','none')));

    end

end
```